# Sharepoint Rest not returning fields with title beginning with a number

Tags: ajax, list, rest, api, sharepoint-online

With this call, I can return all my list items...

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('NXE Action Plan Tracker')/items",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose;" },
    success: function (data) 
    {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) 
    {
        console.log("ERROR: test call");
    },
});
```

...but the data that is returned does not include any fields that begin with a number like "1st Line Review Outcome", how do I return these fields as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is being replaced (escaped):   (Tested in SP2016)

```
Column name:  1st Test
Returned from REST: OData__x0031_st_x0020_test
```

The escaped version works in a select:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/items?$select=Title, OData__x0031_st_x0020_test
```

Comment: Do you know why it escapes these values?

Comment: I'll do some searching, but I'm guessing ODATA does not allow a digit as the first character of a field/column.

Comment: Do you know, if I'm already in the returned item, can I access this value without doing another call?

Comment: You can only access what was in the $select, or in the default list of columns. If you would like to experiment with REST from within SharePoint with writing any code, take a look at a tool I put together: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2017/04/a-sharepoint-rest-api-tester-with-ajax.html